# How to plot columns of a 2D numpy array in interactive window one by one

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 2D numpy array and I want to plot each column in the interactive matplotlib window separately one by one so that I can interactively visualize data in each column.

Doing this in MATLAB was pretty easy. The following MATLAB code gives what I want

```
figure()
for var = 1:size(plantData,2)
    plot(plantData(:,var))
    title(['Variable' int2str(var)])
    pause()
end
```

I tried the following code in python (with Spyder as the editor) but the graph does not appear in the window that comes up.

```
%matplotlib auto
for var in range(plantData.shape[1]):
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(plantData[:,var])
    plt.title('Variable' + str(var))
    plt.show()
    input("Press Enter to continue...")
    plt.close(fig)
```

I expect to see only one column data at a time in the interactive window, then press the Enter key to display another column in the interactive window.

Please help.

Comment: Matplotlib isn't an interactive plotting package. Look at something like bokeh or plot.ly. They've sufficient number of examples which can leverage to graph things the way you want to. In my experience interactive plotting in python using either of the packages above isn't as simple as the code you put for MATLAB. Maybe there is another library which is easier than I'm not aware of. Here is the link for drop down examples - https://plot.ly/python/dropdowns/